# How i can add more column name in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I got one `DataGridView`, with some data from database. I want to add some more columns with this data,

what I mean, I have column like PONO, CreatedDate, Deliverydata, orderedqty, ItemCode,.. now I need to add 3 more column heading and edit it with same data. first column is , receivedqty and second column is TotalValueRecieved and third column is Accept(check box). and I want to update it in the database.

how I can add these columns?

this is my search code with datagridview. what else I have to write here. please help me.

```
Public Sub SelectPONO()
    Try

        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT PONo as 'PO Number',CreatedDate as 'Created Date',DeliveryDate as 'Delivery Date', OrderedQty as 'Ordered Qty',ItemCode as 'Item Code',Price as 'Price' FROM tblPurchaseOrder WHERE PONo='" & txtPONo.Text & "'"
        Dim ds As DataTable = sql.FillDataSet(strSQL)

        dgvPODetails.DataSource = ds
        'DataGridView2.Columns(3).Visible = False
        '   sql.SqlConn.Close()


    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: include `'' as receivedqty,'' as TotalValueRecieved , '' as Accept ` in your `strSQL`

Comment: it will show error... i tried that.

Comment: incorrect systax near keyword as...

Comment: actually where these `receivedqty,TotalValueRecieved  and Accept` column in your db is that in `tblPurchaseOrder` or what?

Comment: as 'Recieved Qty' like this i add the code in between the select command , is it correct?

Comment: where your getting `incorrect systax near keyword` error actually ?

Comment: not in the db.. that 2 columns .

Comment: accept is check box....

Comment: i have one command button called search , insert the  pono in the textbox and press this button it wil show the error

Comment: put screenshot of your code where your are getting this error

Comment: what is meant by sql in "sql.FillDataSet(strSQL)"

Comment: Public Function FillDataSet(ByVal strSQL As String) As DataTable
        OpenDbConnection()
        'SqlConn.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SqlConn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        CloseDbConnection()
        Return dt

    End Function